# Permission in CakePHP Using EC2 Instance

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, cakephp, amazon-ec2

I have new instance in AWS. I have make var/www directory using PuTTy. I have upload all file to var/www/html directory. When i open IP Public Instance in Web Browser there are :

> Warning: _cake_core_ cache was unable to write 'cake_dev_id' to File
>   cache in /var/www/html/lib/Cake/Cache/Cache.php on line 322
>
> Warning: /var/www/html/app/tmp/cache/persistent/ is not writable in
>   /var/www/html/lib/Cake/Cache/Engine/FileEngine.php on line 384

Then i changed permission:

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /var/www/html/lib
sudo chmod -R 777 /var/www/html/app
```

But when i changed the permission there are an error:

> Error: Cannot use 'string' as class name as it is reserved File:
>   /var/www/html/lib/Cake/Utility/String.php Line: 24

Comment: make your `tmp` folder writeable

Comment: my cache folder is in app folder, does cache folder automatic be writeable when is used this sudo chmod -R 777 /var/www/html/app?

Comment: What is your cakephp version ?

Comment: CakePHP Version 2.5.3 sorry

Answer (score 0):

You need to add permission in your `tem` and `logs` folder
if you don't have those folder you need to create those folder
you may use

```
cd /var/www/html/app
mkdir -m 777 tmp
```

Here is the [Official Doc](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/installation.html#permissions)

Comment: When i used setfacl -R -m u:${HTTPDUSER}:rwx tmp, There will be an error: No Such File or Directory

Comment: How? can you tell me what to do?

Comment: try  `mkdir -m 777 tmp`

Answer (score 0):

It clearly saying error is in the class name. You are using `String.php` and `String` is a reserve keyword.

Try Changing the name of `String.php` to something else and try again.

Comment: it still not working, When i change to text the error will be : Cannot declare class text, because the name is already in use

Comment: @wendy so did you change it to `text.php` ?

Comment: yes i have changed it to Text.php but the error is  Error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to ErrorHandler::handleException() must be an instance of Exception, instance of Error given in /var/www/html/lib/Cake/Error/ErrorHandler.php:108 Stack trace: #0 [internal function]: ErrorHandler::handleException(Object(Error)) #1 {main} thrown

Comment: @wendy so now your original error is gone. now its the error because of the code written in the file. you should ask a separate question, putting your code and then you will get help from the community.